# Nested Select or Inner Join including rows from another table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I have a pretty complex select statement that returns counted statistics from tables (think of it as an answer bank -- the complex select statement below) using inner join.

These answers are related to a table called Questions_Bank_AnswerChoices (which stores all the questions).

I am attempting to first pull the Questions (from the table Questions_Bank_AnswerChoices) then match them up with the statistics (complex statement below).   The complex statement below pulls the statistics, but does not pull the questions unless they have been answered.

So, if no one answers question1, then question one will not show up in the statistics because it is not included in the Answers table (bc no one answered it).

How can I achieve this?  I think that I need to outer join?

Complex Select Statement:

```
WITH tbl as (
   SELECT 
      Questions_Bank.QuestionID, Questions_Bank.QuestionName,   
      REPLACE(Schools_Answers_Items.AnswerValue, '? ', ', ') as AnswerValue, 
      COUNT(Schools_Answers_Items.SchoolsAnswersItemID) AS CountAnswer,
      Schools_Answers_Items.SchoolID 
   FROM Questions_Bank 
   INNER JOIN Schools_Answers_Items
     ON Questions_Bank.QuestionID = Schools_Answers_Items.QuestionID 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Schools_Answers  
     ON Schools_Answers_Items.SchoolsAnswerID = Schools_Answers.SchoolsAnswerID 
   WHERE (Questions_Bank.QuestionID = 1108) 
     AND (Schools_Answers.SchoolID = 103) 
   GROUP BY 
      Schools_Answers_Items.SchoolID,         
      Schools_Answers_Items.AnswerValue,
      Questions_Bank.QuestionID, 
      Questions_Bank.QuestionName
) 
SELECT 
   QuestionID, QuestionName, AnswerValue, CountAnswer, 
   SUM(CountAnswer) OVER () AS CountAllAnswers  
FROM tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this

```
INNER JOIN Schools_Answers_Items
  ON Questions_Bank.QuestionID = Schools_Answers_Items.QuestionID
```

to

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN Schools_Answers_Items
  ON Questions_Bank.QuestionID = Schools_Answers_Items.QuestionID
```

and you might want to remove this

```
AND (Schools_Answers.SchoolID = 103)
```

or replace it with this

```
AND (Schools_Answers.SchoolID = 103 OR Schools_Answers.SchoolID IS NULL)
```

---

Try this:

```
   SELECT 
      Questions_Bank.QuestionID, Questions_Bank.QuestionName,   
      REPLACE(Schools_Answers_Items.AnswerValue, '? ', ', ') as AnswerValue,
      Schools_Answers_Items.SchoolID 
   FROM Questions_Bank 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Schools_Answers_Items
     ON Questions_Bank.QuestionID = Schools_Answers_Items.QuestionID 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Schools_Answers  
     ON Schools_Answers_Items.SchoolsAnswerID = Schools_Answers.SchoolsAnswerID 
   WHERE Schools_Answers_Items.SchoolID
```

Comment: That did not work, but I think we are on the right track.  The line:  "ON Questions_Bank.QuestionID = Schools_Answers_Items.QuestionID" says in so many words only join in that case (but sometimes the Schools_Answers_Items.QuestionID does not exist because it was not answered), but I did think outer would fix it?

Comment: LEFT OUTER JOIN should include everything from the table on the LEFT part of the JOIN, which in this case is Questions_Bank.  I'd take off the count field and the grouping and try just a "WHERE SchoolID IS NULL" to see if it's pulling any questions where there are no school answers.